# Reuse looping mediaplayer in android

Tags: android, media-player

how can i properly reuse a `MediaPlayer` in android which is also be looping? (should be initialize as MediaPlayer.setDataSource in the raw folder so that i can use `prepareAsync()`)

Comment: There is a lifecycle for MediaPlayer objects documented here, is this what you're looking for?  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Comment: oh thanks!! i'm wondering, which is more appropriate, call `release()` and initialize the mediaplayer again when i reuse it or just call `stop()` `prepareAsync()` `setOnPreparedListener()` and `start()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to reuse a MediaPlayer, [according to the lifecycle documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html), you should stop() the player, prepare it again with new data, then start it again. I believe the same OnPreparedListener previously set will be invoked again, but you could also reset it *before* preparing.

Once you call release(), the MediaPlayer is no longer usable, so you should only do that when you are completely finished and need it to release resources.

Comment: thank you so much for the help!! much appreciated